# where are meteor logs kept in local dev mode?

Tags: logging, meteor

I know about console.log, but does meteor keep a separate internal log for various errors?

I don't see any useful response from the `check()` function.

> http://docs.meteor.com/#check
>
> to the client, it will appear only as Meteor.Error(400, "Match Failed"); the failure details will be written to the server logs but not revealed to the client.

which is what i get but no error in the server log, that i can see.
perhaps just when the app is deployed to a production env the logging behavior changes?
on an osx machine are there any other system level logs?
I don't see anything in /var/log/

Thanks!

Comment: Check this: https://meteorhacks.com/logging-support-for-meteor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is incorrect. In v0.8.3, `check` does not log failures anywhere. This is being fixed in the next version of meteor as seen [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md):

> When a call to match fails in a method or subscription, log the failure on the server. (This matches the behavior described in our docs)

Answer (score 3):

Logs are not stored locally, they are printed to `stdout` or `stderr`.

You can store those logs using command:

```
meteor > logs.txt
```

and then also have live-preview using:

```
tail -f logs.txt
```

If you want to do that in one line, then:

```
meteor > logs.txt | tail -f logs.txt
```

Comment: you can log to stderr with console.error() too. however my point is that the check() method seems to have its logging output disappear to I don't know where. It's not going to STDERR since that shows up in the normal meteor output. So I can only guess it doesn't go anywhere in dev mode... which makes it not so useful as a checking method. I had to write my own check, using `Match.test(val, pat)`

Comment: Now I see clearly your point. I tried to find the cause of the issue in Meteor source, but no luck so far (need to put more time on it). The difference between `check` and `Match.test` is that `check` throws any Errors and `Match.test` returns `Boolean` in case of `Match.Error`